# Oracle 10g Range Partition Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, partitioning

How can I partition by range for: one for pubdate values less than Jan 1, 2000; one for pubdate values greater than or equal to Jan 1, 2000 and less than Jan 1, 2010; and a third partition for all pubdate values greater than or equal to Jan 1, 2010.

How can I write my query for the partition part? I've tried to look up examples, but I just don't understand what to put after partition.

My query is here:

```
CREATE table lab6_zl (
ID number not null, 
title varchar2(40), 
pubID char(3), 
pubdate date,
constraint lab6_pk primary key(ID))
Partition by range (pubdate)
(Partition one for pubdate values greater than or equal to Jan 1, 2000),
(Partition two for for pubdate values less than Jan 1, 2000),
(Partition three for all pubdate values greater than or equal to Jan 1, 2010);
```

Comment: You're not quite there. I would suggest reading this page: http://www.rampant-books.com/art_nanda_partitioning1.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table LAB6_ZL
(
  ID        number not null
 ,TITLE     varchar2(40)
 ,PUBID     char(3)
 ,PUBDATE   date
 ,constraint LAB6_PK primary key(ID)
)
partition by range (PUBDATE)
  (partition TWO
     values less than (date '2000-01-01')
  ,partition ONE
     values less than (date '2010-01-01')
  ,partition THREE
     values less than (MAXVALUE));
```

The order of the partitions must be ascending so partition `TWO` is created first as it is less than the year 2000 while `ONE` is therefore between 2000 and 2009. The keyword `MAXVALUE` basically means no upper value, or, anything on or after 1st January 2010.